# setting up virtual host on windows apache

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

I need help configuring virtual hosts in apache on Windows.

I have the following in my hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1 ebdowns
```

in httpd-vhosts.conf I have made the following entries:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1> 
    DocumentRoot "C:\wamp\www\"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost www.ebdowns> 
    DocumentRoot "C:\wamp\www\ebdowns"
    ServerName www.ebdowns
    ServerAlias www.ebdowns
    <Directory "C:\wamp\www\ebdowns">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I try to restart apache but with these entries it won't restart. If I remove the first block the server restarts but then when I enter www.ebdowns into my browser it can't find the site located there

Can anyone help let me know where I've gone wrong please

Thanks

Comment: The syntax of your config is not correct. Read the virtualhost documentation. It has a few good examples.

Comment: What is the error message that you get when Apache fails to start ?

Comment: Your question is off topic for Serverfault because it doesn't appear to relate to servers/networking or desktop infrastructure in a professional environment. It may be on topic for [Superuser](http://superuser.com) but please [search](http://superuser.com/search) their site for similar questions that may already have the answer you're looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The IP:PORT pattern in your NameVirtualHost directive must be identical to the one you use in your VirtualHost blocks.

So in your case:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName Localhost
# first virtual host directives
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName ebdowns
    ServerAlias www.ebdowns
# second virtual host directives
</VirtualHost>
```

It's all explained in the documentastion. You should read it.

Answer (score 2):

the hosts file should contain:

```
127.0.0.1 ebdowns www.ebdowns
```